# connect to a service with .NET remoting in a service

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

For obscure reasons I need to connect to a service with .NET remoting from WITHIN the service itself.

To clarify:
there's a client application connecting to the service:

```
IEngine engine = (IEngine)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IEngine), "tcp://169.18.1.100:1966/Engine");
```

When a certain call is made to the service it loads an AppDomain with a plugin dll which computes something. But now this dll needs to call functions from the service its embedded in and it cant call them directly since it lives in its own AppDomain.

So can I just call this from within the AppDomain?

```
IEngine engine = (IEngine)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IEngine), "tcp://localhost:1966/Engine");
```

The object is published with:

```
RemotingServices.Marshal(this, engineUri);
```

It does work for single calls at least, but maybe there's threading and release of the IEngine or other issues to consider?

I hope its clear.

Comment: Is your object configured as a single-call or singleton?

Comment: The object is published with RemotingServices.Marshal(this, engineUri) so I guess its like a singleton

Answer (score 1):

If you store the instance of `IEngine` that was passed to `RemotingServices.Marshal` then you wouldn't need to call `Activator.GetObject` from within the service itself as it will be the same instance used by client applications. It will probably need some re-structuring but it would save any calls to `IEngine` from within your service going over the network stack:

```
IEngine this.engine = new Engine();
RemotingServices.Marshal(this.engine, engineUri);

// this.engine will be the same instance used by client applications and can also be passed around within your service.
```

Comment: it sounded good, but after putting this in the constructor of the assembly class every call returned with null because there's ConfigurationManager settings used inside the methods. I'll stick with Activator.GetObject and fix performance problems if they arise